# Better way to continually run ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, timeout

I have currently got the following code which will run a bunch of ajax requests (40-50) then do them all again. (So do them forever essentially)

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        window.setInterval(function () {
            $('div.env').each(function (index, item) {
                var vm = $(item).text();                    
                var env = "http://localhost:56656/HTML" + vm + ".htm";
                $.ajax(env, {
                    async: false,
                    URL: env,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert("Colouring");
                        var style = $(data).filter('div').attr('style');
                        var styleObj = {};
                        $.each(style.split(';'), function () {
                            var rule = this.split(':');
                            styleObj[$.trim(rule[0])] = $.trim(rule[1]);
                        });

                        $(item).css('background', styleObj.background);

                    },
                    error: function () {

                        $(item).css('background', '#f00');
                    }
                });

            });

        }, 10000);
    });
```

As you can see, I am currently using Timeouts which are running particularly slow on IE and on occasion running slow on chrome. When I say slow, I mean that all the ajax requests will complete then the screen will refresh with the updates. This is the case on IE all the time and occasionally Chrome. Ideally, I would like the ajax to do its requests, update then do the next ajax request.

Any better way to do AJAX requests continually?

Thank you in advance,
James

Comment: What is the data returned by the requests?

Comment: Edit: The requests will return a small html page with just one div in it.

Comment: 40-50? Can't you combine them into a single request?

Comment: You could send an array of json objects, each with a target url, and the id of node consuming the returned data. This could be sent to a central switch which would read the url parameters, get the data, add it to the array of responses, and send back the whole data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [Caolan's async library](https://github.com/caolan/async/). You're code may look like this (after including `async.js` of course):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function call() {
        var calls = [];
        $('div.env').each(function (index, item) {
            calls.push(function(callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    // DO NOT USE async: false!!!!
                    // some ajax settings
                    complete : function() {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        async.parallel(calls, function() {
            /* This will fire when every call finishes.
               You may want to add timeout here, or else
               you will end up flooded with requests. */
            call();
        });
    };
});
```

You should tune it to your needs (`async` can handle errors as well, read the documentation). You said that you want them to fire one after another, so use `async.series` instead of `async.parallel`.

BTW This piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false
```

**PURE EVIL!!!** Blocks every other script and even entire browser!!! That's probably the reason for your "slow-and-blink" problem.

Comment: How long should the timeout be to make it as close to real-time as possible without flooding?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible in your case but websocket/long polling solutions like SignalR or Node.Js + Socket.IO work usually better then continuous polling.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` and do the following:

- if the request fails, do whatever you want :)
- if the request succeeds, recall with `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an architecture issue rather than anything else.

I would recommend to rebuild the structure to send an array to the server, and to send the response combined into one html page or [json object](http://www.json.org/)

The reason for this is quote obviously, that no matter what you do, 40-50 concurrent ajax request requests will most definitively **always be slow**, because even if your ajax success handler (function you bind to success) is done in 10ms (which it surely isn't on IE because of its complexity), 40 requests mean **at least 400ms exclusive time**, leading to client performance problems. In your case,

```
async: false
```

even adds the request time to that exclusive time, so if your requests finish in 10ms (highly unlikely), you use another 400ms of client exclusive time.

So, searching for a solution on the client side is not really an option here.